# Fastest way to generate space before string

Tags: java

Hello currently I'm looking for answer what is the fastest way to generate space before string and writing it.

let say i have variable int howDeep = 0;

currently I'm doing it in this way:

```
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(System.out));


out.println("    ".repeat(Math.max(0, howDeep)) + actualString);
```

but well if howDeep is for example 2100 then it is kinda expensive so if I process this code with random howDeep values and random string it is a lot of data to write.

How can I firstly generate this spaces in good time secondly how to write data in fast way?

Comment: I don't think there is. You need to print 2100 chars, don't think there is a way to skip that. It's just like, reading 1000 input, and you're asking for a way that doesn't read the input one by one.

Comment: what are your performance criteria and how do you define "good time?"

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    System.out.print(String.format("%-"+howDeep+"s","") + actualString);
```

`String.format("%-"+howDeep+"s","")` will do the padding.

Comment: Note that this fails for 0. If Spaces are randomly generated you need to make sure howDeep is greater than or equal to 1

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use `String#indent` provided you are working with java 12 or higher.

```
String actualString = "FooBar";
System.out.println(actualString.indent(13));
```

But I am not sure if it gives you performance advantages

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity sake I performed some testing to compare the presented methods as well as the StringBuilder approach. To do that I attempted the following methods:

1. using String.format (Credit goes to @zzssrko)
2. using indent (Credit goes to @Eritrean)
3. using repeat
4. using stringBuilder

My findings stem from executing the attached program multiple times and comparing the results. Generally speaking as long as your application is not extremely memory bounded or does this operation very very frequently on insanely long string it does not matter much.

Surprisingly indent() seems to perform the worst while the other options are about equal. Interestingly format and repeat seem to even beat the StringBuilder.

Takeaway use format or repeat

```
public class Tst {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int STRLEN = 100000;
        String st1 = "control string length using STRLEN".repeat(STRLEN);
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            int spaces = i * 10000;
            System.out.println("using a string of length " + st1.length() + "with " + spaces + " spaces");
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            perfFormat(st1, spaces);
            long formatEnd = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            perfIndent(st1, spaces);
            long indentEnd = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            perfRepeat(st1, spaces);
            long repeatEnd = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            perfStringBuilder(st1, spaces);
            long sbEnd = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
            System.out.println("fmt\t|\tind\t|\trep\t|\tsb\t");
            System.out.println(formatEnd + "\t|\t" + indentEnd + "\t|\t" + repeatEnd + "\t|\t" + sbEnd + "\t");
        }
    }

    public static String perfStringBuilder(String s, int spaces) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++)
            sb.append(' ');
        sb.append(s);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String perfIndent(String s, int spaces) {
        return s.indent(spaces);
    }

    public static String perfFormat(String s, int spaces) {
        return String.format("%-" + spaces + "s", "") + s;
    }

    public static String perfRepeat(String s, int spaces) {
        return " ".repeat(spaces) + s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you generally have indentation, the almost *fastest* way would be:

```
for (int i = Math.max(0, howDeep); i > 0; --i) {
    out.print("    ");
}
out.println(actualString);
```

This does no string concatenation.

You could create one single large String with spaces. And just take a substring.
But that seems rather micro-optimisation; being less readable. And System.out is not that fast. Better would be to use a **logger** for speed.